# Using javascript in a php module loaded by Ajax, to return error values even if the request has been successful

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a main page written in php, where i use Ajax to load "modules" in a given `div`. I stripped a bit the code, of course, but i think the main things are there: the call to `load()`, the check for the successful (or not) ajax request and the check for the js variable "returned" from php (i'll explain this last later); this is the javascript:

```
var ajax_error = ""; //i use this to catch load errors

//.....//

$("#div_target").load("loadmodule.php", {'module':module_number}, function(response, status, xhr)
{
  if (status == "error") //this is for ajax-related errors
  {
    alert('Failed loading module. Error: '+xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
  else 
  {
    //this checks if the variable has been set by the php module to represent an error
    if (ajax_error !== "")
    {
      $("#div_target").html(ajax_error); //show the error instead of the module
      ajax_error = ""; //we reset the variable for future uses
    }
    else
    {
      //do something with the correctly loaded module..
    }
  }
});
```

That "loadmodule.php" is the subsequent (again, the code is reduced):

```
//check for the post value, that should be a positive number as well as check for the file to exist
if ( 
  isset($_POST['module']) 
  && is_numeric($_POST['module']) 
  && ($_POST['module'] > 0) 
  && file_exists("module_" . $_POST['module'] . ".php")
)
{
  //include module
  include("module_{$_POST['module']}.php");
}
else
{
  //error retrieving module
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ajax_error = "Cannot load module." ;
  </script>
  <?php
}
```

This way, in case of any error while checking for the `$_POST['module']`, we can "tell" javascript that an error occurred just by setting the variable `ajax_error`, which will be "catched" after ajax successfully completed the request. Everything works well (the context for this variable `ajax_error` is correct, even if it doesn't really look so, in the stripped code here :P), but..

..my question(s) is(are): is this method correct? Are there any problems doing that? Is there something that looks less as a workaround? Or am i just doing the best i can do in this situation?

PS: I found it hard to give a title to my question, hope it's ok :)

Comment: This should probably be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte maybe i'm on the edge between codereview and stackoverflow..if others think the same thing, i'll move my question there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this may work, but seems ugly to me.
I would suggest not using $obj.load, but [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).
The server script (loadmodule.php) will not return pure HTML, but JSON with two values: one boolean flag determining if the module exists, second the HTML content.

then, the success handler will decide if to put something to the desired  or display an error message if the flag tells that module doesn't exist.

Comment: Should i put an entire (and complex) HTML module into the JSON returned by the server script? I mean, it's not a matter of some HTML rows, but a bug DOM structure

Comment: yes. don't forget to use json_encode. it's a completely pure way to return data through AJAX.